# Optional parameter of the \item command in the margin: is that behaviour normal?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[A very long line that will be in the margin of my document]
This is a test 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: A "blatant overlap"]

but no warning in the `log` file (no overfull box whatsoever).

1. Is there any mechanism to get sure that the text in the optional field of `item` will be printed?
2. How acceptable is it to write the legend, or presentation, of an item in the margins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the way lists a physically built:  label boxes are right-aligned at the *list* left margin, having the effect of an `\llap{labelbox}` command.

The solution consists in setting the `align=left` key from the `enumitem` package and suppressing the label indent from the *page* left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\vskip1cm
\begin{itemize}[align = left]
  \item[A very long line that will be in the margin of my document]
        This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

  \item A normal item.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And an additional thanks for the explanation regarding `\llap`.