# \item[With very long bullet point], making a design brief

Tags: tables, itemize

I'm writing a list for a design brief which looks like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Feasibility guarantee:} \label{req1} 
    \begin{itemize}
         \item[Specification:] The solution of the hydraulic model bla bla bla 3 lines of text
         \item[Test:] The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text
     \end{itemize}
\item \textbf{Certifiable optimality:} \label{req2} 
     \begin{itemize}
          \item[Specification:] The optimality bla bla bla 6 lines of text
           \item[Test:] It must be possible to prove  bla bla bla 3 lines of text
     \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
```

and the result is:[image]

and as you can see the yellow highlighted bits are outside of the text box.

So my question is: How to move the item indent further to the right, or even better, what other latex methods are there to make such a design brief. I tried a table but it doesn't look very nice.

Comment: Did you try a `description` environment, `\begin{description}\item[Label] Text \item[Another label] Text \end{description}`?

Comment: No, never heard of it. Going to look into it now.

Comment: Somehow related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241107/34551

Comment: @gernot I've tried the `description` environment  and also the simple `paragraph` one, but it doesn't look quite like what I wanted. But thanks for mentioning an environment I'd never heard of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem  comes  from the way labels are aligned: for `enumerate` and `itemize`, by default, they're placed at the left of the list left margin and right-aligned. For the `description` environment, the label is placed on the `text` left margin, and left-aligned; the same is true for the `wide` option of `enumitem`, except the label is placed at a fixed distance of the text left margin (defaults to `parindent), and the`list`left margin is the`text`left margin; this maybe changed with the`leftmargin=` key.

Illustration with 3 possibilities:

```
        \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%

     \usepackage{enumitem}

        \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Feasibility guarantee:} \label{req1}
        \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, font=\normalfont\itshape]
             \item[Specification:] The solution of the hydraulic model bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of textl bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of textl bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text
             \item[Test:] The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text.
             \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Certifiable optimality:} \label{req2}
         \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, font=\normalfont\itshape]
              \item[Specification:] The optimality bla bla bla 6 lines of text
               \item[Test:] It must be possible to prove bla bla bla 3 lines of text
         \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
    \bigskip
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Feasibility guarantee:} \label{req1}
        \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, font=\normalfont\itshape]
             \item[Specification:] The solution of the hydraulic model bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of textl bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of textl bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text
             \item[Test:] The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text.
             \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Certifiable optimality:} \label{req2}
         \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, font=\normalfont\itshape]
              \item[Specification:] The optimality bla bla bla 6 lines of text
               \item[Test:] It must be possible to prove bla bla bla 3 lines of text
         \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
    \bigskip
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Feasibility guarantee:} \label{req1}
        \begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape]
             \item[Specification:] The solution of the hydraulic model bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of textl bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of textl bla bla bla 3 lines of text bla bla bla 3 lines of text
             \item[Test:] The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text. The error found when comparing bla bla bla 5 lines of text.
             \end{description}

    \item \textbf{Certifiable optimality:} \label{req2}
         \begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape]
              \item[Specification:] The optimality bla bla bla 6 lines of text
               \item[Test:] It must be possible to prove bla bla bla 3 lines of text
         \end{description}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]